# Android Widget - Update from my Activity

Tags: android, android-widget

I have added a widget and instead of updating it every xxx minutes, I want to update it only if something is changed in my Activity.

But, how can I call the `onUpdate` routine of my widget from my activity?

Comment: When you say "something is changed", what kinds of changes are you looking for?

Comment: My widget shows the active alarms of my app.
I want to update the widget if the user deletes or adds a new alarm.

Instead of checking every x minutes for update, i want to force the update wihtin my activity.

Answer (score 0):

> But how can i call the onUpdate Routine of my widget from my activity?

Put the `onUpdate()` logic someplace else, reachable by both your `AppWidgetProvider` and your activity. It could be that the "someplace else" is an `IntentService` (so the provider and activity would call `startService()` to send the command over), or it could be that the "someplace else" is just a static method somewhere.

Comment: So i need to start a service in the AppWidgetProvider and my activity should talk to that service? The service itself does the update to the Widget?

Answer (score 0):

In the `onUpdate()` Method of the `AppWidgetProvider`, I start a service!
The service does update the widget.

`public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
context.startService(new Intent(context, WidgetActiveReminders.UpdateService.class));
}`

The service is located in my `AppWidgetProvider` as public class.

In my Activity, I start the same service and the started service which updates the widget.
So, it is possible to inform the widget about a new update.

`Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
context.startService(intent);`